# What is a semi-simple eigenvalue of a linear operator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

What is a semi-simple eigenvalue of a linear operator? I know that for a matrix a semi-simple eigenvalue is the one for which geometric and algebraic multiplicity coincide. How does that generalise to the case of linear bounded operators?

Does it have something to do with the fact that there exists a contour of the complex plane around this eigenvalue dividing the spectrum of the operator into two disjoint parts?